# Custom directive two ways binding not working

Tags: angularjs

All,Forgive me I just began learning to use angluarjs. and I was trying to implement 2-ways binding to a model in my custom directive. But I don't know why it doesn't work. Please help to review it . thanks.

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="childController" >
  <div class='col-lg-1'>
     <search-Input bind-Model="seachInputResult"/>
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-1'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary pull-right form-group' type='button' ng-click="create()">create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
     var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

        });

        app.controller('childController', function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.testModel={text:""};
            $scope.elementValues={name:"joe"};
        });

        app.value('testSource', [{value:"111",text:"111text",type:"a"},
                                 {value:"222",text:"222text",type:"b"},
                                 {value:"333",text:"333text",type:"c"},
                                 {value:"444",text:"444text",type:"d"}]);

        app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $log,testSource) {
            $scope.seachInputResult={text:"2222", 
                    value:""
                        };

            $scope.create = function(){
                //debugger;
                alert($scope.seachInputResult.type);
            };
        });

        app.directive("searchInput",function(testSource){
            searchDir = {};
            searchDir.restrict="E";
            searchDir.replace="true";
            searchDir.template="<div class=\"input-group dropdown\">"+
                    "<input class=\"form-control dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" " + 
                        "autocomplete=\"off\"" +
                        "ng-model=\"bindModel.text\" ></input>"+
                    "<span class=\"input-group-addon\">"+
                        "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search text-muted\"></i>" + 
                    "</span>" + 
                    "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">" +
                        "<li ng-repeat=\"data in elementDefinition.itemDatas\">" +
                            "<a ng-click=\"selectItem($index)\">" +
        "<div ng-bind=\"data.text\" ></div></a></li></ul></div>";  
            searchDir.scope={
                bindModel:'='
            };
            searchDir.link=function (scope, jqElement, attrs) {           
                scope.elementDefinition={};
                scope.elementDefinition.itemDatas = testSource;
                scope.selectItem = function(index){
                    var value = scope.elementDefinition.itemDatas[index];
                    scope.bindModel=value;//trying to update the binding model. doesn't work
                };
            }
            return searchDir;
        });
```

The `searchInputResult` model is exist the `AppController`, and I used isolated scope in my custom directive. I tried to use `bindModel` in directive scope to bind `searchInputResult` . and also want to update the binding model in the function `selectItem`.

Please see the demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/hcBG5/3/). thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcBG5/4/):

Change in this line to make it work:

```
<search-Input bind-Model="$parent.seachInputResult"/></div>
```

And change the alert so you get the correct output:

```
alert($scope.seachInputResult.text);
```

It's correct that the `seachInputResult` is on the child controller but in order to achieve two-way binding you need to communicate with the parent controller.

Comment: I had thought if the childController doesn't found the `seachInputResult` . It will search it in its parent scope which is belong `AppController`. Why? :o

Comment: It would, for it's value. but for tw o-way-bind you have to work with an object on the parent controller. waht you did was working with a premptive. check this post for further abstraction. it's a recommended one.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Ben, You mean the primitive type ? Did I ?

Comment: seachInputResult is not primitive type , It is a object .right ? And according to the wiki doc.  the scope of nested controllers is prototype inheritance. which means child scope would have the property of it parents. right ?

Comment: Right, right and right. But - the best practice to avoid this situation is to nest object when dealing with to way binding. I refered to it as a primitive and it was a mistake, I should say a scope object. 

 "best practice" of always have a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use 
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">.

Comment: Ben, I don't know why , Angular just recognize the variable without dot `.` as a primitive in isolated scope of custom directive. So we just followed the best practice to solved the issue.